# Kotlin: how to check if 2 date ranges are overlapping?

Tags: kotlin, date, range, overlap

my current solution is like this:

```
(A.startAt in B.startAt..B.endAt) || 
    (A.endAt in B.startAt..B.endAt) || 
    (A.startAt <= B.startAt && A.endAt >= B.endAt)
```

if there is more idiomatic or performant check, please help me.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the other question IMHO, since the OP asks for a more idiomatic solution in kotlin, while the other question is tagged language-agnostic

Answer (score 4):

How about `max(A.startAt,B.startAt)<=min(A.endAt,B.endAt)`

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant (in my subjective opinion) is probably

```
val overlap = a.intersect(b).isNotEmpty()
```

Or you could do

```
a.any { b.contains(it) }
// or a.any(b::contains)
```

which should avoid creating a new collection (which `intersect` does) - I feel like it's less immediately obvious what it's doing though, the first one reads better to me.

---

You *could* manually work out if the start or end of one range is between the start and end of the other, which is probably the "most efficient" way - that can be a little tricky though because you can have descending ranges, which aren't `IntRange`s, they're just `IntProgression`s (which an `IntRange` is a subclass of). So you'd have to do this kind of thing:

```
fun overlap(a: IntProgression, b: IntProgression): Boolean {
    val max = maxOf(a.first, a.last)
    val min = minOf(a.first, a.last)
    return (b.first >= min && b.first <= max) || (b.last >= min && b.last <= max)
}
```

and I mean, is it really worth it? (Maybe it is! But you should benchmark it if so, because you're adding complexity and there should be a concrete benefit to that tradeoff)

Comment: Won't the `any()` solution perform badly?

Comment: @gidds depends! It's inefficient (*O(n)*), but it should just be iterators vs creating collections of all the elements in a range, so it's a time vs memory tradeoff. The function is the most efficient, but it's the most complex/least "idiomatic". I just like to give people options when the question asks something like "what's the most efficient and also most elegant/idiomatic approach" because those are often mutually exclusive things, and they'll have to decide which is more important to them. (I wouldn't use the `any` one myself personally, but it's good to know you *could* I think!)

Comment: this is the best answer for sure

Answer (score 0):

```
B.endAt >= A.startAt && B.startAt <= A.endAt
```